# Java ClassCastException which makes absolutely no sense

Tags: casting, option-type, classcastexception

I am getting the following casting exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.model.Bucket cannot be cast to java.util.Optional
    at com.service.BucketServiceTest.testGetById(BucketServiceTest.java:65)
```

However, nowhere in my code am I trying to cast to an `Optional`:

```
@Test
public void testGetById() {
    Mockito.when(bucketRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenAnswer(invocationOnMock -> testBucket);
    String bucketName = bucketService.getBucketById(testBucket.getId()).getName();
    assertEquals(bucketName, testBucket.getName());
}
```

Line 65 is `String bucketName = bucketService.getBucketById(testBucket.getId()).getName();`

The `getBucketById` method returns type `bucket` and NOT `optional`:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Bucket getBucketById(long id) {
    return (Bucket) bucketRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
```

Therefore I have no idea where `Bucket` is being cast to `Optional`, and so this error makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't recompiled after recent changes. Can you confirm that this is actually the line it is complaining about (e.g. by adding an exception breakpoint in your IDE)? It might be the previous line. Can you check the generic typing of `Mockito.when` and `thenAnswer`?  And wouldn't `thenReturn` be a better fit in this situation?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody has the same issue, It worked for me like this

> when(repository.findById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(element));